# Split Function for Text String Using Multi-character delimeter in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, split

I found this code on an older posting on this site and modified it.  It was originally designed to handle only a comma delimiter.  I need to make it robust enough to handle a multi-character delimiter.

For example test below the delimiter is '!@@!'

1234  !@@! 345 !@@! 654 !@@! 789

I can't seem to get it to work 100% correctly when the entire strings @txt is greater than 8,000 characters in length.  Line 1 of output is correct, line 2 is incorrect, and then all remaining lines of output are correct.

Any thoughts or proposed edits?

See below for the code.

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[Func_SplitStr3] ( 
        @txt text,
        @StrDelimeter varchar(8000)
) 
Returns @tmp Table 
        ( 
                Id int primary key IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
                Data varchar(8000)
        ) 
as 
BEGIN 
declare @str varchar(8000) 
             ,@Beg int 
       ,@last int 
       ,@size int 

        set @size=datalength(@txt) 
        set @Beg=1 
        set @str=substring(@txt,@Beg,8000) 

        IF len(@str)<8000 
                            set @Beg=@size 
        ELSE BEGIN 
                set @last=charindex(reverse(@StrDelimeter), reverse(@str)) + LEN(@StrDelimeter) - 1 
                set @str=substring(@txt,@Beg,8000-@last) 
                set @Beg=@Beg+8000-@last+LEN(@StrDelimeter) +1                 
        END 

        declare @workingString varchar(8000) 
                , @stringindex int 

        while @Beg<=@size Begin 
                WHILE LEN(@str) > 0 BEGIN 
                        SELECT @StringIndex = CHARINDEX(@StrDelimeter, @str)
                        SELECT @workingString = 
                        CASE 
                               WHEN @StringIndex > 0 
                               THEN SUBSTRING(@str, 1, @StringIndex - 1) 
                               ELSE @str 
                               END 

                        INSERT INTO 
                                @tmp(Data)
                        VALUES 
                                (cast(rtrim(ltrim(@workingString)) as varchar(8000)))
                        SELECT @str = CASE 
                                WHEN CHARINDEX(@StrDelimeter, @str) > 0 
                                THEN SUBSTRING(@str, @StringIndex + LEN(@StrDelimeter), LEN(@str) - LEN(@StrDelimeter) -1)               
                                ELSE '' 
                        END 
                END 
                set @str=substring(@txt,@Beg,8000) 

                if @Beg=@size set @Beg=@Beg +1
                else IF len(@str)<8000 set @Beg=@size 
                ELSE BEGIN 
                        set @last=charindex(reverse(@StrDelimeter), reverse(@str)) + LEN(@StrDelimeter) -1
                        set @str=substring(@txt,@Beg,8000-@last) 
                        set @Beg=@Beg+8000-@last+LEN(@StrDelimeter)

                END 
        END     
        Return
END
GO
```

See below for some test data:

```
[Chain_Name]99999 CUSTOMER[Chain_Name/][Outlet_ID]2[Outlet_ID/][Outlet_Type]TEST[Outlet_Type/][Prod_RTM]RTM_1[Prod_RTM/][Prod_name]PRODUCT 1[Prod_name/][PL_Info]Volume (in Widgets)!@@!1000000.0!@@!1050000.0!@@!1150000.0!@@!1250000.0!@@!1350000.0!@@!1450000.0!@@!1550000.0!@@!1650000.0!@@!1750000.0!@@!1850000.0!@@!1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Cases)!@@!400000.0!@@!420000.0!@@!460000.0!@@!500000.0!@@!540000.0!@@!580000.0!@@!620000.0!@@!660000.0!@@!700000.0!@@!740000.0!@@!780000.0!^^!Volume (in Pallets)!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Gross Revenue!@@!13250000.0!@@!13914024.657534245!@@!15848736.657534245!@@!17915963.178082194!@@!20123209.841621917!@@!22478370.697159894!@@!24989747.285394307!@@!27666068.607572015!@@!30516512.039867323!@@!33550725.23697413!@@!36778849.0705857!^^!Distribution Costs!@@!-1269230.7692307692!@@!-1332838.3561643837!@@!-1518166.3561643837!@@!-1716188.0547945208!@@!-1927622.4231452055!@@!-2153225.6400762745!@@!-2393792.918484796!@@!-2650160.4181418773!@@!-2923207.2491019503!@@!-3213857.5698698014!@@!-3523082.784700517!^^!Discounts!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Variable Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Fixed Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Allowances!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Commissions!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Expense!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Service Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Lease Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Net of Revenue!@@!-375000.0!@@!-393750.0!@@!-444187.5!@@!-497296.875!@@!-553193.04375!@@!-611995.4154375001!@@!-673828.055686875!@@!-738819.8584773188!@@!-807104.7241850711!@@!-878821.7439626589!@@!-954115.3906751354!^^!Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Yield Losses!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Sales Tax!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Amortization!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Other Deductions!@@!-80274.9210996844!@@!-963299.0531962127!@@!-2568797.4751899005!@@!-4174295.8971835887!@@!-5779794.319177276!@@!-7385292.741170964!@@!-8990791.163164653!@@!-10589598.67048468!@@!-12154959.631928528!@@!-13405855.631202525!@@!-13379100.0!^^!Total Deductions!@@!-1724505.6903304537!@@!-2689887.4093605964!@@!-4531151.331354285!@@!-6387780.826978109!@@!-8260609.786072481!@@!-10150513.796684738!@@!-12058412.137336325!@@!-13978578.947103877!@@!-15885271.60521555!@@!-17498534.945034984!@@!-17856298.17537565!^^!Net Revenue!@@!11525494.309669547!@@!11224137.248173648!@@!11317585.32617996!@@!11528182.351104084!@@!11862600.055549435!@@!12327856.900475156!@@!12931335.148057982!@@!13687489.660468139!@@!14631240.434651773!@@!16052190.291939147!@@!18922550.89521005!^^!COGS!@@!-2823529.411764706!@@!-2964868.3319903305!@@!-3312181.479452055!@@!-3672201.2054794524!@@!-4045296.847956165!@@!-4431847.435649754!@@!-4832241.928111904!@@!-5246879.461298279!@@!-5676169.599040868!@@!-6120532.590508638!@@!-6580399.633795503!^^!Gross Profit/Contr. Margin!@@!8701964.897904841!@@!8259268.916183317!@@!8005403.846727905!@@!7855981.145624632!@@!7817303.20759327!@@!7896009.464825402!@@!8099093.219946078!@@!8440610.19916986!@@!8955070.835610906!@@!9931657.701430509!@@!12342151.261414547!^^!DME!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Direct OPEX!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!Indirect OPEX!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Total OPEX (Cash)!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!EBITDA/COP!@@!8021382.373632996!@@!7544598.530493731!@@!7199187.587823795!@@!6953369.464460248!@@!6813237.97346601!@@!6785215.815070541!@@!6876071.108336673!@@!7099625.632279419!@@!7490146.786023015!@@!8336564.686293523!@@!10610397.57444015!^^!Other Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Total OPEX (non-Cash)!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!EBIT/PBT/OI/NOP!@@!8021382.373632996!@@!7544598.530493731!@@!7199187.587823795!@@!6953369.464460248!@@!6813237.97346601!@@!6785215.815070541!@@!6876071.108336673!@@!7099625.632279419!@@!7490146.786023015!@@!8336564.686293523!@@!10610397.57444015!^^!Income Taxes!@@!-3048125.3019805383!@@!-2866947.4415876176!@@!-2735691.283373042!@@!-2642280.3964948943!@@!-2589030.4299170836!@@!-2578382.0097268056!@@!-2612907.021167936!@@!-2697857.740266179!@@!-2846255.7786887456!@@!-3167894.5807915386!@@!-4031951.078287257!^^!Net Income/NOPAT!@@!4973257.071652458!@@!4677651.088906113!@@!4463496.304450753!@@!4311089.067965354!@@!4224207.543548927!@@!4206833.805343735!@@!4263164.087168737!@@!4401767.89201324!@@!4643891.00733427!@@!5168670.105501984!@@!6578446.496152893!^^!Receivables!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!TVM on Advance Funding!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Equipment!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!PP&E!@@!824410.325!@@!865630.84125!@@!948071.87375!@@!1030512.90625!@@!1112953.93875!@@!1195394.97125!@@!1277836.00375!@@!1360277.03625!@@!1442718.06875!@@!1525159.10125!@@!1607600.13375!^^!Capital Charge!@@!-125195.04822222222!@@!-728704.4617307519!@@!-1672994.1955153074!@@!-2489436.542685573!@@!-3178065.061713453!@@!-3738915.047769173!@@!-4172023.617963588!@@!-4477697.437218106!@@!-4657583.037023307!@@!-4725640.01343713!@@!-4745598.371129533!^^!Economic Profit!@@!4848062.023430236!@@!3948946.627175361!@@!2790502.1089354455!@@!1821652.525279781!@@!1046142.481835474!@@!467918.757574562!@@!91140.469205149!@@!-75929.545204866!@@!-13692.029689037!@@!443030.092064854!@@!1832848.12502336[PL_Info/]!%%![Chain_Name]99999 CUSTOMER[Chain_Name/][Outlet_ID]2[Outlet_ID/][Outlet_Type]TEST[Outlet_Type/][Prod_RTM]RTM_1[Prod_RTM/][Prod_name]PRODUCT 2[Prod_name/][PL_Info]Volume (in Widgets)!@@!1000000.0!@@!1050000.0!@@!1150000.0!@@!1250000.0!@@!1350000.0!@@!1450000.0!@@!1550000.0!@@!1650000.0!@@!1750000.0!@@!1850000.0!@@!1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Cases)!@@!1000000.0!@@!1050000.0!@@!1150000.0!@@!1250000.0!@@!1350000.0!@@!1450000.0!@@!1550000.0!@@!1650000.0!@@!1750000.0!@@!1850000.0!@@!1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Pallets)!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Gross Revenue!@@!83413461.53846154!@@!87593732.87671232!@@!99773432.87671232!@@!112787358.90410958!@@!126682761.52109589!@@!141509336.57319453!@@!157319345.2110273!@@!174167739.60136956!@@!192112294.5906016!@@!211213745.59561002!@@!231535933.00967413!^^!Distribution Costs!@@!-2192307.692307692!@@!-2302175.3424657527!@@!-2622287.342465753!@@!-2964324.821917808!@@!-3329529.6399780815!@@!-3719207.9237681096!@@!-4134733.222837373!@@!-4577549.813154151!@@!-5049176.15753973!@@!-5551208.529775109!@@!-6085324.809937255!^^!Discounts!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Variable Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Fixed Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Allowances!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Commissions!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Expense!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Service Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Lease Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Net of Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Yield Losses!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Sales Tax!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Amortization!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Other Deductions!@@!-415981.6666666666!@@!-4991780.000000001!@@!-13207417.916666668!@@!-21319060.41666667!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!^^!Total Deductions!@@!-2608289.3589743585!@@!-7293955.342465754!@@!-15829705.25913242!@@!-24283385.238584477!@@!-28288429.639978085!@@!-28678107.923768114!@@!-29093633.222837377!@@!-29536449.813154154!@@!-30008076.157539733!@@!-30510108.529775113!@@!-31044224.809937257!^^!Net Revenue!@@!80805172.17948718!@@!80299777.53424656!@@!83943727.6175799!@@!88503973.66552511!@@!98394331.8811178!@@!112831228.64942642!@@!128225711.98818992!@@!144631289.7882154!@@!162104218.43306187!@@!180703637.0658349!@@!200491708.19973686!^^!COGS!@@!-53921568.62745098!@@!-56620749.395648666!@@!-63253465.75342465!@@!-70128842.46575342!@@!-77253932.86027399!@@!-84635975.33358903!@@!-92282397.9326926!@@!-100200823.04562686!@@!-108399072.20390545!@@!-116885170.99929689!@@!-125667354.11762244!^^!Gross Profit/Contr. Margin!@@!26883603.5520362!@@!23679028.138597894!@@!20690261.86415525!@@!18375131.19977169!@@!21140399.02084381!@@!28195253.31583739!@@!35943314.05549732!@@!44430466.74258854!@@!53705146.22915642!@@!63818466.06653801!@@!74824354.08211441!^^!DME!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Direct OPEX!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!Indirect OPEX!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Total OPEX (Cash)!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!EBITDA/COP!@@!26203021.027764354!@@!22964357.752908308!@@!19884045.60525114!@@!17472519.518607307!@@!20136333.78671655!@@!27084459.666082527!@@!34720291.94388791!@@!43089482.1756981!@@!52240222.17956853!@@!62223373.05140103!@@!73092600.39514!^^!Other Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Total OPEX (non-Cash)!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!EBIT/PBT/OI/NOP!@@!26203021.027764354!@@!22964357.752908308!@@!19884045.60525114!@@!17472519.518607307!@@!20136333.78671655!@@!27084459.666082527!@@!34720291.94388791!@@!43089482.1756981!@@!52240222.17956853!@@!62223373.05140103!@@!73092600.39514!^^!Income Taxes!@@!-9957147.990550455!@@!-8726455.946105158!@@!-7555937.329995433!@@!-6639557.417070776!@@!-7651806.838952289!@@!-10292094.67311136!@@!-13193710.938677406!@@!-16374003.226765279!@@!-19851284.42823604!@@!-23644881.759532392!@@!-27775188.1501532!^^!Net Income/NOPAT!@@!16245873.0372139!@@!14237901.80680315!@@!12328108.275255706!@@!10832962.101536531!@@!12484526.94776426!@@!16792364.992971167!@@!21526581.005210504!@@!26715478.948932823!@@!32388937.75133249!@@!38578491.291868635!@@!45317412.2449868!^^!Receivables!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!TVM on Advance Funding!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Equipment!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!PP&E!@@!3424500.0!@@!3595725.0!@@!3938175.0!@@!4280625.0!@@!4623075.0!@@!4965525.0!@@!5307975.0!@@!5650425.0!@@!5992875.0!@@!6335325.0!@@!6677775.0!^^!Capital Charge!@@!-646910.8547008547!@@!-1644376.7789954336!@@!-2994973.654328767!@@!-3696209.230255708!@@!-3931326.702623211!@@!-4025013.967078372!@@!-4123098.272365749!@@!-4225825.31572879!@@!-4333453.41492509!@@!-4446254.124751928!@@!-4564512.882701032!^^!Economic Profit!@@!15598962.182513045!@@!12593525.027807716!@@!9333134.620926939!@@!7136752.871280823!@@!8553200.24514105!@@!12767351.025892794!@@!17403482.732844755!@@!22489653.63320403!@@!28055484.3364074!@@!34132237.16711671!@@!40752899.36228577[PL_Info/]!%%![Chain_Name]99999 CUSTOMER[Chain_Name/][Outlet_ID]2[Outlet_ID/][Outlet_Type]TEST[Outlet_Type/][Prod_RTM]RTM_1[Prod_RTM/][Prod_name]PRODUCT 3[Prod_name/][PL_Info]Volume (in Widgets)!@@!1000000.0!@@!1050000.0!@@!1150000.0!@@!1250000.0!@@!1350000.0!@@!1450000.0!@@!1550000.0!@@!1650000.0!@@!1750000.0!@@!1850000.0!@@!1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Cases)!@@!1000000.0!@@!1050000.0!@@!1150000.0!@@!1250000.0!@@!1350000.0!@@!1450000.0!@@!1550000.0!@@!1650000.0!@@!1750000.0!@@!1850000.0!@@!1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Pallets)!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Gross Revenue!@@!83413461.53846154!@@!87593732.87671232!@@!99773432.87671232!@@!112787358.90410958!@@!126682761.52109589!@@!141509336.57319453!@@!157319345.2110273!@@!174167739.60136956!@@!192112294.5906016!@@!211213745.59561002!@@!231535933.00967413!^^!Distribution Costs!@@!-2192307.692307692!@@!-2302175.3424657527!@@!-2622287.342465753!@@!-2964324.821917808!@@!-3329529.6399780815!@@!-3719207.9237681096!@@!-4134733.222837373!@@!-4577549.813154151!@@!-5049176.15753973!@@!-5551208.529775109!@@!-6085324.809937255!^^!Discounts!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Variable Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Fixed Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Allowances!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Commissions!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Expense!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Service Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Lease Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Net of Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Yield Losses!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Sales Tax!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Amortization!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Other Deductions!@@!-415981.6666666666!@@!-4991780.000000001!@@!-13207417.916666668!@@!-21319060.41666667!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!^^!Total Deductions!@@!-2608289.3589743585!@@!-7293955.342465754!@@!-15829705.25913242!@@!-24283385.238584477!@@!-28288429.639978085!@@!-28678107.923768114!@@!-29093633.222837377!@@!-29536449.813154154!@@!-30008076.157539733!@@!-30510108.529775113!@@!-31044224.809937257!^^!Net Revenue!@@!80805172.17948718!@@!80299777.53424656!@@!83943727.6175799!@@!88503973.66552511!@@!98394331.8811178!@@!112831228.64942642!@@!128225711.98818992!@@!144631289.7882154!@@!162104218.43306187!@@!180703637.0658349!@@!200491708.19973686!^^!COGS!@@!-53921568.62745098!@@!-56620749.395648666!@@!-63253465.75342465!@@!-70128842.46575342!@@!-77253932.86027399!@@!-84635975.33358903!@@!-92282397.9326926!@@!-100200823.04562686!@@!-108399072.20390545!@@!-116885170.99929689!@@!-125667354.11762244!^^!Gross Profit/Contr. Margin!@@!26883603.5520362!@@!23679028.138597894!@@!20690261.86415525!@@!18375131.19977169!@@!21140399.02084381!@@!28195253.31583739!@@!35943314.05549732!@@!44430466.74258854!@@!53705146.22915642!@@!63818466.06653801!@@!74824354.08211441!^^!DME!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Direct OPEX!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!Indirect OPEX!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Total OPEX (Cash)!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!EBITDA/COP!@@!26203021.027764354!@@!22964357.752908308!@@!19884045.60525114!@@!17472519.518607307!@@!20136333.78671655!@@!27084459.666082527!@@!34720291.94388791!@@!43089482.1756981!@@!52240222.17956853!@@!62223373.05140103!@@!73092600.39514!^^!Other Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Total OPEX (non-Cash)!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!EBIT/PBT/OI/NOP!@@!26203021.027764354!@@!22964357.752908308!@@!19884045.60525114!@@!17472519.518607307!@@!20136333.78671655!@@!27084459.666082527!@@!34720291.94388791!@@!43089482.1756981!@@!52240222.17956853!@@!62223373.05140103!@@!73092600.39514!^^!Income Taxes!@@!-9957147.990550455!@@!-8726455.946105158!@@!-7555937.329995433!@@!-6639557.417070776!@@!-7651806.838952289!@@!-10292094.67311136!@@!-13193710.938677406!@@!-16374003.226765279!@@!-19851284.42823604!@@!-23644881.759532392!@@!-27775188.1501532!^^!Net Income/NOPAT!@@!16245873.0372139!@@!14237901.80680315!@@!12328108.275255706!@@!10832962.101536531!@@!12484526.94776426!@@!16792364.992971167!@@!21526581.005210504!@@!26715478.948932823!@@!32388937.75133249!@@!38578491.291868635!@@!45317412.2449868!^^!Receivables!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!TVM on Advance Funding!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Equipment!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!PP&E!@@!3424500.0!@@!3595725.0!@@!3938175.0!@@!4280625.0!@@!4623075.0!@@!4965525.0!@@!5307975.0!@@!5650425.0!@@!5992875.0!@@!6335325.0!@@!6677775.0!^^!Capital Charge!@@!-646910.8547008547!@@!-1644376.7789954336!@@!-2994973.654328767!@@!-3696209.230255708!@@!-3931326.702623211!@@!-4025013.967078372!@@!-4123098.272365749!@@!-4225825.31572879!@@!-4333453.41492509!@@!-4446254.124751928!@@!-4564512.882701032!^^!Economic Profit!@@!15598962.182513045!@@!12593525.027807716!@@!9333134.620926939!@@!7136752.871280823!@@!8553200.24514105!@@!12767351.025892794!@@!17403482.732844755!@@!22489653.63320403!@@!28055484.3364074!@@!34132237.16711671!@@!40752899.36228577[PL_Info/]!%%![Chain_Name]99999 CUSTOMER[Chain_Name/][Outlet_ID]2[Outlet_ID/][Outlet_Type]TEST[Outlet_Type/][Prod_RTM]RTM_1[Prod_RTM/][Prod_name]PRODUCT 4[Prod_name/][PL_Info]Volume (in Widgets)!@@!1000000.0!@@!1050000.0!@@!1150000.0!@@!1250000.0!@@!1350000.0!@@!1450000.0!@@!1550000.0!@@!1650000.0!@@!1750000.0!@@!1850000.0!@@!1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Cases)!@@!1000000.0!@@!1050000.0!@@!1150000.0!@@!1250000.0!@@!1350000.0!@@!1450000.0!@@!1550000.0!@@!1650000.0!@@!1750000.0!@@!1850000.0!@@!1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Pallets)!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Gross Revenue!@@!83413461.53846154!@@!87593732.87671232!@@!99773432.87671232!@@!112787358.90410958!@@!126682761.52109589!@@!141509336.57319453!@@!157319345.2110273!@@!174167739.60136956!@@!192112294.5906016!@@!211213745.59561002!@@!231535933.00967413!^^!Distribution Costs!@@!-2192307.692307692!@@!-2302175.3424657527!@@!-2622287.342465753!@@!-2964324.821917808!@@!-3329529.6399780815!@@!-3719207.9237681096!@@!-4134733.222837373!@@!-4577549.813154151!@@!-5049176.15753973!@@!-5551208.529775109!@@!-6085324.809937255!^^!Discounts!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Variable Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Fixed Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Allowances!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Commissions!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Expense!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Service Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Lease Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Net of Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Yield Losses!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Sales Tax!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Amortization!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Other Deductions!@@!-415981.6666666666!@@!-4991780.000000001!@@!-13207417.916666668!@@!-21319060.41666667!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!^^!Total Deductions!@@!-2608289.3589743585!@@!-7293955.342465754!@@!-15829705.25913242!@@!-24283385.238584477!@@!-28288429.639978085!@@!-28678107.923768114!@@!-29093633.222837377!@@!-29536449.813154154!@@!-30008076.157539733!@@!-30510108.529775113!@@!-31044224.809937257!^^!Net Revenue!@@!80805172.17948718!@@!80299777.53424656!@@!83943727.6175799!@@!88503973.66552511!@@!98394331.8811178!@@!112831228.64942642!@@!128225711.98818992!@@!144631289.7882154!@@!162104218.43306187!@@!180703637.0658349!@@!200491708.19973686!^^!COGS!@@!-53921568.62745098!@@!-56620749.395648666!@@!-63253465.75342465!@@!-70128842.46575342!@@!-77253932.86027399!@@!-84635975.33358903!@@!-92282397.9326926!@@!-100200823.04562686!@@!-108399072.20390545!@@!-116885170.99929689!@@!-125667354.11762244!^^!Gross Profit/Contr. Margin!@@!26883603.5520362!@@!23679028.138597894!@@!20690261.86415525!@@!18375131.19977169!@@!21140399.02084381!@@!28195253.31583739!@@!35943314.05549732!@@!44430466.74258854!@@!53705146.22915642!@@!63818466.06653801!@@!74824354.08211441!^^!DME!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Direct OPEX!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!Indirect OPEX!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Total OPEX (Cash)!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!EBITDA/COP!@@!26203021.027764354!@@!22964357.752908308!@@!19884045.60525114!@@!17472519.518607307!@@!20136333.78671655!@@!27084459.666082527!@@!34720291.94388791!@@!43089482.1756981!@@!52240222.17956853!@@!62223373.05140103!@@!73092600.39514!^^!Other Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Total OPEX (non-Cash)!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!EBIT/PBT/OI/NOP!@@!26203021.027764354!@@!22964357.752908308!@@!19884045.60525114!@@!17472519.518607307!@@!20136333.78671655!@@!27084459.666082527!@@!34720291.94388791!@@!43089482.1756981!@@!52240222.17956853!@@!62223373.05140103!@@!73092600.39514!^^!Income Taxes!@@!-9957147.990550455!@@!-8726455.946105158!@@!-7555937.329995433!@@!-6639557.417070776!@@!-7651806.838952289!@@!-10292094.67311136!@@!-13193710.938677406!@@!-16374003.226765279!@@!-19851284.42823604!@@!-23644881.759532392!@@!-27775188.1501532!^^!Net Income/NOPAT!@@!16245873.0372139!@@!14237901.80680315!@@!12328108.275255706!@@!10832962.101536531!@@!12484526.94776426!@@!16792364.992971167!@@!21526581.005210504!@@!26715478.948932823!@@!32388937.75133249!@@!38578491.291868635!@@!45317412.2449868!^^!Receivables!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!TVM on Advance Funding!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Equipment!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!PP&E!@@!3424500.0!@@!3595725.0!@@!3938175.0!@@!4280625.0!@@!4623075.0!@@!4965525.0!@@!5307975.0!@@!5650425.0!@@!5992875.0!@@!6335325.0!@@!6677775.0!^^!Capital Charge!@@!-646910.8547008547!@@!-1644376.7789954336!@@!-2994973.654328767!@@!-3696209.230255708!@@!-3931326.702623211!@@!-4025013.967078372!@@!-4123098.272365749!@@!-4225825.31572879!@@!-4333453.41492509!@@!-4446254.124751928!@@!-4564512.882701032!^^!Economic Profit!@@!15598962.182513045!@@!12593525.027807716!@@!9333134.620926939!@@!7136752.871280823!@@!8553200.24514105!@@!12767351.025892794!@@!17403482.732844755!@@!22489653.63320403!@@!28055484.3364074!@@!34132237.16711671!@@!40752899.36228577[PL_Info/]
```

Comment: don't use text. use nvarchar(max). Also, get rid of the 8000 character declarations and replace with MAX

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Is that test data a single value passed in to be split? Am I not seeing something correctly? It appears that the sample data is not splittable in this manner to begin with, at least not yet. There are multiple levels of splitting to be done before you get to the data that is delimited by `'!@@!'`. Please be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish, and what the final output (given that sample input) should look like. As it is, it certainly looks like splitting on `'!@@!'` is the least of your problems. And why so many levels of delimiters instead of using XML?

Answer (score 0):

### Split Functions

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split_Multi]  
    (  
      @delimited NVARCHAR(MAX),  
      @delimiter NVARCHAR(100)  
    )   
 RETURNS @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val NVARCHAR(MAX))  
AS  
BEGIN  
  DECLARE @xml XML  
  SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@delimited,@delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'  

  INSERT INTO @t(val)  
  SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as item  
  FROM  @xml.nodes('/t') as records(r)  
  RETURN  
END
```

### Test

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Value VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
('1234 !@@! 345 !@@! 654 !@@! 789')

SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(Val)) AS [Values]
FROM @TABLE t CROSS APPLY [dbo].[split_Multi](t.Value, '!@@!')
```

### Result

```
Values
1234
345
654
789
```

Comment: M.Ali thanks for your post.  However, I tried it and it didn't work with my data.  I'm posting some better test data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Go
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split_function] (@STRING    VARCHAR(MAX),
                                        @delimiter VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS @rowdata TABLE (
  rowdata VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @rowdata
                  (rowdata)
      SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)') col3
      FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>'
                           + Replace((SELECT @STRING + '' FOR xml path('')), @delimiter, '</M><M>')
                           + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
             CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)

      RETURN
  END

SELECT *
FROM
[dbo].[Split_function]('[Chain_Name]99999 CUSTOMER[Chain_Name/][Outlet_ID]2[Outlet_ID/][Outlet_Type]TEST[Outlet_Type/][Prod_RTM]RTM_1[Prod_RTM/][Prod_name]PRODUCT 1[Prod_name/][PL_Info]Volume (in Widgets)!@@!1000000.0!@@!1050000.0!@@!1150000.0!@@!1250000.0!@@!1350000.0!@@!1450000.0!@@!1550000.0!@@!1650000.0!@@!1750000.0!@@!1850000.0!@@!1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Cases)!@@!400000.0!@@!420000.0!@@!460000.0!@@!500000.0!@@!540000.0!@@!580000.0!@@!620000.0!@@!660000.0!@@!700000.0!@@!740000.0!@@!780000.0!^^!Volume (in Pallets)!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Gross Revenue!@@!13250000.0!@@!13914024.657534245!@@!15848736.657534245!@@!17915963.178082194!@@!20123209.841621917!@@!22478370.697159894!@@!24989747.285394307!@@!27666068.607572015!@@!30516512.039867323!@@!33550725.23697413!@@!36778849.0705857!^^!Distribution Costs!@@!-1269230.7692307692!@@!-1332838.3561643837!@@!-1518166.3561643837!@@!-1716188.0547945208!@@!-1927622.4231452055!@@!-2153225.6400762745!@@!-2393792.918484796!@@!-2650160.4181418773!@@!-2923207.2491019503!@@!-3213857.5698698014!@@!-3523082.784700517!^^!Discounts!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Variable Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Fixed Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Allowances!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Commissions!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Expense!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Service Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Lease Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Net of Revenue!@@!-375000.0!@@!-393750.0!@@!-444187.5!@@!-497296.875!@@!-553193.04375!@@!-611995.4154375001!@@!-673828.055686875!@@!-738819.8584773188!@@!-807104.7241850711!@@!-878821.7439626589!@@!-954115.3906751354!^^!Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Yield Losses!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Sales Tax!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Amortization!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Other Deductions!@@!-80274.9210996844!@@!-963299.0531962127!@@!-2568797.4751899005!@@!-4174295.8971835887!@@!-5779794.319177276!@@!-7385292.741170964!@@!-8990791.163164653!@@!-10589598.67048468!@@!-12154959.631928528!@@!-13405855.631202525!@@!-13379100.0!^^!Total Deductions!@@!-1724505.6903304537!@@!-2689887.4093605964!@@!-4531151.331354285!@@!-6387780.826978109!@@!-8260609.786072481!@@!-10150513.796684738!@@!-12058412.137336325!@@!-13978578.947103877!@@!-15885271.60521555!@@!-17498534.945034984!@@!-17856298.17537565!^^!Net Revenue!@@!11525494.309669547!@@!11224137.248173648!@@!11317585.32617996!@@!11528182.351104084!@@!11862600.055549435!@@!12327856.900475156!@@!12931335.148057982!@@!13687489.660468139!@@!14631240.434651773!@@!16052190.291939147!@@!18922550.89521005!^^!COGS!@@!-2823529.411764706!@@!-2964868.3319903305!@@!-3312181.479452055!@@!-3672201.2054794524!@@!-4045296.847956165!@@!-4431847.435649754!@@!-4832241.928111904!@@!-5246879.461298279!@@!-5676169.599040868!@@!-6120532.590508638!@@!-6580399.633795503!^^!Gross Profit/Contr. Margin!@@!8701964.897904841!@@!8259268.916183317!@@!8005403.846727905!@@!7855981.145624632!@@!7817303.20759327!@@!7896009.464825402!@@!8099093.219946078!@@!8440610.19916986!@@!8955070.835610906!@@!9931657.701430509!@@!12342151.261414547!^^!DME!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Direct OPEX!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!Indirect OPEX!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Total OPEX (Cash)!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!EBITDA/COP!@@!8021382.373632996!@@!7544598.530493731!@@!7199187.587823795!@@!6953369.464460248!@@!6813237.97346601!@@!6785215.815070541!@@!6876071.108336673!@@!7099625.632279419!@@!7490146.786023015!@@!8336564.686293523!@@!10610397.57444015!^^!Other Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Total OPEX (non-Cash)!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!EBIT/PBT/OI/NOP!@@!8021382.373632996!@@!7544598.530493731!@@!7199187.587823795!@@!6953369.464460248!@@!6813237.97346601!@@!6785215.815070541!@@!6876071.108336673!@@!7099625.632279419!@@!7490146.786023015!@@!8336564.686293523!@@!10610397.57444015!^^!Income Taxes!@@!-3048125.3019805383!@@!-2866947.4415876176!@@!-2735691.283373042!@@!-2642280.3964948943!@@!-2589030.4299170836!@@!-2578382.0097268056!@@!-2612907.021167936!@@!-2697857.740266179!@@!-2846255.7786887456!@@!-3167894.5807915386!@@!-4031951.078287257!^^!Net Income/NOPAT!@@!4973257.071652458!@@!4677651.088906113!@@!4463496.304450753!@@!4311089.067965354!@@!4224207.543548927!@@!4206833.805343735!@@!4263164.087168737!@@!4401767.89201324!@@!4643891.00733427!@@!5168670.105501984!@@!6578446.496152893!^^!Receivables!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!TVM on Advance Funding!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Equipment!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!PP&E!@@!824410.325!@@!865630.84125!@@!948071.87375!@@!1030512.90625!@@!1112953.93875!@@!1195394.97125!@@!1277836.00375!@@!1360277.03625!@@!1442718.06875!@@!1525159.10125!@@!1607600.13375!^^!Capital Charge!@@!-125195.04822222222!@@!-728704.4617307519!@@!-1672994.1955153074!@@!-2489436.542685573!@@!-3178065.061713453!@@!-3738915.047769173!@@!-4172023.617963588!@@!-4477697.437218106!@@!-4657583.037023307!@@!-4725640.01343713!@@!-4745598.371129533!^^!Economic Profit!@@!4848062.023430236!@@!3948946.627175361!@@!2790502.1089354455!@@!1821652.525279781!@@!1046142.481835474!@@!467918.757574562!@@!91140.469205149!@@!-75929.545204866!@@!-13692.029689037!@@!443030.092064854!@@!1832848.12502336[PL_Info/]!%%![Chain_Name]99999 CUSTOMER[Chain_Name/][Outlet_ID]2[Outlet_ID/][Outlet_Type]TEST[Outlet_Type/][Prod_RTM]RTM_1[Prod_RTM/][Prod_name]PRODUCT 2[Prod_name/][PL_Info]Volume (in Widgets)!@@!1000000.0!@@!1050000.0!@@!1150000.0!@@!1250000.0!@@!1350000.0!@@!1450000.0!@@!1550000.0!@@!1650000.0!@@!1750000.0!@@!1850000.0!@@!1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Cases)!@@!1000000.0!@@!1050000.0!@@!1150000.0!@@!1250000.0!@@!1350000.0!@@!1450000.0!@@!1550000.0!@@!1650000.0!@@!1750000.0!@@!1850000.0!@@!1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Pallets)!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Gross Revenue!@@!83413461.53846154!@@!87593732.87671232!@@!99773432.87671232!@@!112787358.90410958!@@!126682761.52109589!@@!141509336.57319453!@@!157319345.2110273!@@!174167739.60136956!@@!192112294.5906016!@@!211213745.59561002!@@!231535933.00967413!^^!Distribution Costs!@@!-2192307.692307692!@@!-2302175.3424657527!@@!-2622287.342465753!@@!-2964324.821917808!@@!-3329529.6399780815!@@!-3719207.9237681096!@@!-4134733.222837373!@@!-4577549.813154151!@@!-5049176.15753973!@@!-5551208.529775109!@@!-6085324.809937255!^^!Discounts!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Variable Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Fixed Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Allowances!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Commissions!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Expense!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Service Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Lease Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Net of Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Yield Losses!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Sales Tax!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Amortization!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Other Deductions!@@!-415981.6666666666!@@!-4991780.000000001!@@!-13207417.916666668!@@!-21319060.41666667!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!^^!Total Deductions!@@!-2608289.3589743585!@@!-7293955.342465754!@@!-15829705.25913242!@@!-24283385.238584477!@@!-28288429.639978085!@@!-28678107.923768114!@@!-29093633.222837377!@@!-29536449.813154154!@@!-30008076.157539733!@@!-30510108.529775113!@@!-31044224.809937257!^^!Net Revenue!@@!80805172.17948718!@@!80299777.53424656!@@!83943727.6175799!@@!88503973.66552511!@@!98394331.8811178!@@!112831228.64942642!@@!128225711.98818992!@@!144631289.7882154!@@!162104218.43306187!@@!180703637.0658349!@@!200491708.19973686!^^!COGS!@@!-53921568.62745098!@@!-56620749.395648666!@@!-63253465.75342465!@@!-70128842.46575342!@@!-77253932.86027399!@@!-84635975.33358903!@@!-92282397.9326926!@@!-100200823.04562686!@@!-108399072.20390545!@@!-116885170.99929689!@@!-125667354.11762244!^^!Gross Profit/Contr. Margin!@@!26883603.5520362!@@!23679028.138597894!@@!20690261.86415525!@@!18375131.19977169!@@!21140399.02084381!@@!28195253.31583739!@@!35943314.05549732!@@!44430466.74258854!@@!53705146.22915642!@@!63818466.06653801!@@!74824354.08211441!^^!DME!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Direct OPEX!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!Indirect OPEX!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Total OPEX (Cash)!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!EBITDA/COP!@@!26203021.027764354!@@!22964357.752908308!@@!19884045.60525114!@@!17472519.518607307!@@!20136333.78671655!@@!27084459.666082527!@@!34720291.94388791!@@!43089482.1756981!@@!52240222.17956853!@@!62223373.05140103!@@!73092600.39514!^^!Other Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Total OPEX (non-Cash)!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!EBIT/PBT/OI/NOP!@@!26203021.027764354!@@!22964357.752908308!@@!19884045.60525114!@@!17472519.518607307!@@!20136333.78671655!@@!27084459.666082527!@@!34720291.94388791!@@!43089482.1756981!@@!52240222.17956853!@@!62223373.05140103!@@!73092600.39514!^^!Income Taxes!@@!-9957147.990550455!@@!-8726455.946105158!@@!-7555937.329995433!@@!-6639557.417070776!@@!-7651806.838952289!@@!-10292094.67311136!@@!-13193710.938677406!@@!-16374003.226765279!@@!-19851284.42823604!@@!-23644881.759532392!@@!-27775188.1501532!^^!Net Income/NOPAT!@@!16245873.0372139!@@!14237901.80680315!@@!12328108.275255706!@@!10832962.101536531!@@!12484526.94776426!@@!16792364.992971167!@@!21526581.005210504!@@!26715478.948932823!@@!32388937.75133249!@@!38578491.291868635!@@!45317412.2449868!^^!Receivables!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!TVM on Advance Funding!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Equipment!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!PP&E!@@!3424500.0!@@!3595725.0!@@!3938175.0!@@!4280625.0!@@!4623075.0!@@!4965525.0!@@!5307975.0!@@!5650425.0!@@!5992875.0!@@!6335325.0!@@!6677775.0!^^!Capital Charge!@@!-646910.8547008547!@@!-1644376.7789954336!@@!-2994973.654328767!@@!-3696209.230255708!@@!-3931326.702623211!@@!-4025013.967078372!@@!-4123098.272365749!@@!-4225825.31572879!@@!-4333453.41492509!@@!-4446254.124751928!@@!-4564512.882701032!^^!Economic Profit!@@!15598962.182513045!@@!12593525.027807716!@@!9333134.620926939!@@!7136752.871280823!@@!8553200.24514105!@@!12767351.025892794!@@!17403482.732844755!@@!22489653.63320403!@@!28055484.3364074!@@!34132237.16711671!@@!40752899.36228577[PL_Info/]!%%![Chain_Name]99999 CUSTOMER[Chain_Name/][Outlet_ID]2[Outlet_ID/][Outlet_Type]TEST[Outlet_Type/][Prod_RTM]RTM_1[Prod_RTM/][Prod_name]PRODUCT 3[Prod_name/][PL_Info]Volume (in Widgets)!@@!1000000.0!@@!1050000.0!@@!1150000.0!@@!1250000.0!@@!1350000.0!@@!1450000.0!@@!1550000.0!@@!1650000.0!@@!1750000.0!@@!1850000.0!@@!1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Cases)!@@!1000000.0!@@!1050000.0!@@!1150000.0!@@!1250000.0!@@!1350000.0!@@!1450000.0!@@!1550000.0!@@!1650000.0!@@!1750000.0!@@!1850000.0!@@!1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Pallets)!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Gross Revenue!@@!83413461.53846154!@@!87593732.87671232!@@!99773432.87671232!@@!112787358.90410958!@@!126682761.52109589!@@!141509336.57319453!@@!157319345.2110273!@@!174167739.60136956!@@!192112294.5906016!@@!211213745.59561002!@@!231535933.00967413!^^!Distribution Costs!@@!-2192307.692307692!@@!-2302175.3424657527!@@!-2622287.342465753!@@!-2964324.821917808!@@!-3329529.6399780815!@@!-3719207.9237681096!@@!-4134733.222837373!@@!-4577549.813154151!@@!-5049176.15753973!@@!-5551208.529775109!@@!-6085324.809937255!^^!Discounts!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Variable Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Fixed Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Allowances!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Commissions!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Expense!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Service Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Lease Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Net of Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Yield Losses!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Sales Tax!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Amortization!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Other Deductions!@@!-415981.6666666666!@@!-4991780.000000001!@@!-13207417.916666668!@@!-21319060.41666667!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!^^!Total Deductions!@@!-2608289.3589743585!@@!-7293955.342465754!@@!-15829705.25913242!@@!-24283385.238584477!@@!-28288429.639978085!@@!-28678107.923768114!@@!-29093633.222837377!@@!-29536449.813154154!@@!-30008076.157539733!@@!-30510108.529775113!@@!-31044224.809937257!^^!Net Revenue!@@!80805172.17948718!@@!80299777.53424656!@@!83943727.6175799!@@!88503973.66552511!@@!98394331.8811178!@@!112831228.64942642!@@!128225711.98818992!@@!144631289.7882154!@@!162104218.43306187!@@!180703637.0658349!@@!200491708.19973686!^^!COGS!@@!-53921568.62745098!@@!-56620749.395648666!@@!-63253465.75342465!@@!-70128842.46575342!@@!-77253932.86027399!@@!-84635975.33358903!@@!-92282397.9326926!@@!-100200823.04562686!@@!-108399072.20390545!@@!-116885170.99929689!@@!-125667354.11762244!^^!Gross Profit/Contr. Margin!@@!26883603.5520362!@@!23679028.138597894!@@!20690261.86415525!@@!18375131.19977169!@@!21140399.02084381!@@!28195253.31583739!@@!35943314.05549732!@@!44430466.74258854!@@!53705146.22915642!@@!63818466.06653801!@@!74824354.08211441!^^!DME!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Direct OPEX!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!Indirect OPEX!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Total OPEX (Cash)!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!EBITDA/COP!@@!26203021.027764354!@@!22964357.752908308!@@!19884045.60525114!@@!17472519.518607307!@@!20136333.78671655!@@!27084459.666082527!@@!34720291.94388791!@@!43089482.1756981!@@!52240222.17956853!@@!62223373.05140103!@@!73092600.39514!^^!Other Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Total OPEX (non-Cash)!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!EBIT/PBT/OI/NOP!@@!26203021.027764354!@@!22964357.752908308!@@!19884045.60525114!@@!17472519.518607307!@@!20136333.78671655!@@!27084459.666082527!@@!34720291.94388791!@@!43089482.1756981!@@!52240222.17956853!@@!62223373.05140103!@@!73092600.39514!^^!Income Taxes!@@!-9957147.990550455!@@!-8726455.946105158!@@!-7555937.329995433!@@!-6639557.417070776!@@!-7651806.838952289!@@!-10292094.67311136!@@!-13193710.938677406!@@!-16374003.226765279!@@!-19851284.42823604!@@!-23644881.759532392!@@!-27775188.1501532!^^!Net Income/NOPAT!@@!16245873.0372139!@@!14237901.80680315!@@!12328108.275255706!@@!10832962.101536531!@@!12484526.94776426!@@!16792364.992971167!@@!21526581.005210504!@@!26715478.948932823!@@!32388937.75133249!@@!38578491.291868635!@@!45317412.2449868!^^!Receivables!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!TVM on Advance Funding!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Equipment!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!PP&E!@@!3424500.0!@@!3595725.0!@@!3938175.0!@@!4280625.0!@@!4623075.0!@@!4965525.0!@@!5307975.0!@@!5650425.0!@@!5992875.0!@@!6335325.0!@@!6677775.0!^^!Capital Charge!@@!-646910.8547008547!@@!-1644376.7789954336!@@!-2994973.654328767!@@!-3696209.230255708!@@!-3931326.702623211!@@!-4025013.967078372!@@!-4123098.272365749!@@!-4225825.31572879!@@!-4333453.41492509!@@!-4446254.124751928!@@!-4564512.882701032!^^!Economic Profit!@@!15598962.182513045!@@!12593525.027807716!@@!9333134.620926939!@@!7136752.871280823!@@!8553200.24514105!@@!12767351.025892794!@@!17403482.732844755!@@!22489653.63320403!@@!28055484.3364074!@@!34132237.16711671!@@!40752899.36228577[PL_Info/]!%%![Chain_Name]99999 CUSTOMER[Chain_Name/][Outlet_ID]2[Outlet_ID/][Outlet_Type]TEST[Outlet_Type/][Prod_RTM]RTM_1[Prod_RTM/][Prod_name]PRODUCT 4[Prod_name/][PL_Info]Volume (in Widgets)!@@!1000000.0!@@!1050000.0!@@!1150000.0!@@!1250000.0!@@!1350000.0!@@!1450000.0!@@!1550000.0!@@!1650000.0!@@!1750000.0!@@!1850000.0!@@!1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Cases)!@@!1000000.0!@@!1050000.0!@@!1150000.0!@@!1250000.0!@@!1350000.0!@@!1450000.0!@@!1550000.0!@@!1650000.0!@@!1750000.0!@@!1850000.0!@@!1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Pallets)!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Gross Revenue!@@!83413461.53846154!@@!87593732.87671232!@@!99773432.87671232!@@!112787358.90410958!@@!126682761.52109589!@@!141509336.57319453!@@!157319345.2110273!@@!174167739.60136956!@@!192112294.5906016!@@!211213745.59561002!@@!231535933.00967413!^^!Distribution Costs!@@!-2192307.692307692!@@!-2302175.3424657527!@@!-2622287.342465753!@@!-2964324.821917808!@@!-3329529.6399780815!@@!-3719207.9237681096!@@!-4134733.222837373!@@!-4577549.813154151!@@!-5049176.15753973!@@!-5551208.529775109!@@!-6085324.809937255!^^!Discounts!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Variable Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Fixed Funding!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Allowances!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Commissions!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Expense!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Service Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Lease Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Service Net of Revenue!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Yield Losses!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Sales Tax!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Amortization!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Other Deductions!@@!-415981.6666666666!@@!-4991780.000000001!@@!-13207417.916666668!@@!-21319060.41666667!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!@@!-24958900.000000004!^^!Total Deductions!@@!-2608289.3589743585!@@!-7293955.342465754!@@!-15829705.25913242!@@!-24283385.238584477!@@!-28288429.639978085!@@!-28678107.923768114!@@!-29093633.222837377!@@!-29536449.813154154!@@!-30008076.157539733!@@!-30510108.529775113!@@!-31044224.809937257!^^!Net Revenue!@@!80805172.17948718!@@!80299777.53424656!@@!83943727.6175799!@@!88503973.66552511!@@!98394331.8811178!@@!112831228.64942642!@@!128225711.98818992!@@!144631289.7882154!@@!162104218.43306187!@@!180703637.0658349!@@!200491708.19973686!^^!COGS!@@!-53921568.62745098!@@!-56620749.395648666!@@!-63253465.75342465!@@!-70128842.46575342!@@!-77253932.86027399!@@!-84635975.33358903!@@!-92282397.9326926!@@!-100200823.04562686!@@!-108399072.20390545!@@!-116885170.99929689!@@!-125667354.11762244!^^!Gross Profit/Contr. Margin!@@!26883603.5520362!@@!23679028.138597894!@@!20690261.86415525!@@!18375131.19977169!@@!21140399.02084381!@@!28195253.31583739!@@!35943314.05549732!@@!44430466.74258854!@@!53705146.22915642!@@!63818466.06653801!@@!74824354.08211441!^^!DME!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Direct OPEX!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!Indirect OPEX!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Total OPEX (Cash)!@@!-680582.5242718447!@@!-714670.3856895863!@@!-806216.2589041096!@@!-902611.6811643835!@@!-1004065.2341272603!@@!-1110793.6497548618!@@!-1223022.1116094047!@@!-1340984.5668904406!@@!-1464924.0495878907!@@!-1595093.015136986!@@!-1731753.6869743983!^^!EBITDA/COP!@@!26203021.027764354!@@!22964357.752908308!@@!19884045.60525114!@@!17472519.518607307!@@!20136333.78671655!@@!27084459.666082527!@@!34720291.94388791!@@!43089482.1756981!@@!52240222.17956853!@@!62223373.05140103!@@!73092600.39514!^^!Other Depreciation!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!Total OPEX (non-Cash)!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!@@!0.0!^^!EBIT/PBT/OI/NOP!@@!26203021.027764354!@@!22964357.752908308!@@!19884045.60525114!@@!17472519.518607307!@@!20136333.78671655!@@!27084459.666082527!@@!34720291.94388791!@@!43089482.1756981!@@!52240222.17956853!@@!62223373.05140103!@@!73092600.39514!^^!Income Taxes!@@!-9957147.990550455!@@!-8726455.946105158!@@!-7555937.329995433!@@!-6639557.417070776!@@!-7651806.838952289!@@!-10292094.67311136!@@!-13193710.938677406!@@!-16374003.226765279!@@!-19851284.42823604!@@!-23644881.759532392!@@!-27775188.1501532!^^!Net Income/NOPAT!@@!16245873.0372139!@@!14237901.80680315!@@!12328108.275255706!@@!10832962.101536531!@@!12484526.94776426!@@!16792364.992971167!@@!21526581.005210504!@@!26715478.948932823!@@!32388937.75133249!@@!38578491.291868635!@@!45317412.2449868!^^!Receivables!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!TVM on Advance Funding!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!Equipment!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!@@!0!^^!PP&E!@@!3424500.0!@@!3595725.0!@@!3938175.0!@@!4280625.0!@@!4623075.0!@@!4965525.0!@@!5307975.0!@@!5650425.0!@@!5992875.0!@@!6335325.0!@@!6677775.0!^^!Capital Charge!@@!-646910.8547008547!@@!-1644376.7789954336!@@!-2994973.654328767!@@!-3696209.230255708!@@!-3931326.702623211!@@!-4025013.967078372!@@!-4123098.272365749!@@!-4225825.31572879!@@!-4333453.41492509!@@!-4446254.124751928!@@!-4564512.882701032!^^!Economic Profit!@@!15598962.182513045!@@!12593525.027807716!@@!9333134.620926939!@@!7136752.871280823!@@!8553200.24514105!@@!12767351.025892794!@@!17403482.732844755!@@!22489653.63320403!@@!28055484.3364074!@@!34132237.16711671!@@!40752899.36228577[PL_Info/]', '!@@!')
```

Sample output

```
rowdata
---------
[Chain_Name]99999 CUSTOMER[Chain_Name/][Outlet_ID]2[Outlet_ID/][Outlet_Type]TEST[Outlet_Type/][Prod_RTM]RTM_1[Prod_RTM/][Prod_name]PRODUCT 1[Prod_name/][PL_Info]Volume (in Widgets)
1000000.0
1050000.0
1150000.0
1250000.0
1350000.0
1450000.0
1550000.0
1650000.0
1750000.0
1850000.0
1950000.0!^^!Volume (in Cases)
400000.0
420000.0
460000.0
500000.0
540000.0
580000.0
620000.0
660000.0
700000.0
740000.0
780000.0!^^!Volume (in Pallets)
0
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Secondary Issue: your statement that it errors when data greater that 8000 chars is sent.  This is due to the limitation of the data type.

Variable-length, non-Unicode character data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000

Change to varchar(max) as both of the responses indicate.